how to always select "commit and push" in vs code
I'm new to Vs Code
I know I can click the drop down menu and select "commit and push" and am using this feature often.

after it pushes the commit, the button changes to "Commit".
I want to disable this behavior and keep the button "Commit and Push"
how do I do that?

I found it!

it was Git: Post Commit Command

File > Preferences > Settings
in search bar type git : post commit command
set it : commitandPush
